# Django/Channels: AppRegistryNotReady error when deploying ASGI application on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-rest-framework, daphne

I'm encountering an issue when deploying my Django application with Channels (ASGI) on Heroku. I've set up my ASGI configuration and routing as per the documentation, and the application works fine locally. However, when I deploy it on Heroku, I'm getting the following error:

**heroku log**

```
`2023-09-29T13:50:20.958856+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2023-09-29T13:50:24.630050+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `daphne nanochat.asgi:application --port 16299 --bind 0.0.0.0 -v2`
2023-09-29T13:50:25.627718+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-09-29T13:50:25.627755+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/daphne", line 8, in <module>
2023-09-29T13:50:25.627769+00:00 app[web.1]: sys.exit(CommandLineInterface.entrypoint())
2023-09-29T13:50:25.627785+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/daphne/cli.py", line 171, in entrypoint
2023-09-29T13:50:25.627826+00:00 app[web.1]: cls().run(sys.argv[1:])
2023-09-29T13:50:25.627827+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/daphne/cli.py", line 233, in run
2023-09-29T13:50:25.627875+00:00 app[web.1]: application = import_by_path(args.application)
2023-09-29T13:50:25.627876+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/daphne/utils.py", line 12, in import_by_path
2023-09-29T13:50:25.627909+00:00 app[web.1]: target = importlib.import_module(module_path)
2023-09-29T13:50:25.627909+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2023-09-29T13:50:25.627951+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2023-09-29T13:50:25.627952+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
2023-09-29T13:50:25.628008+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
2023-09-29T13:50:25.628030+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2023-09-29T13:50:25.628055+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
2023-09-29T13:50:25.628081+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
2023-09-29T13:50:25.628117+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
2023-09-29T13:50:25.628142+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/./nanochat/asgi.py", line 16, in <module>
2023-09-29T13:50:25.628169+00:00 app[web.1]: import chat.routing
2023-09-29T13:50:25.628170+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/./chat/routing.py", line 3, in <module>
2023-09-29T13:50:25.628195+00:00 app[web.1]: from . import consumers
2023-09-29T13:50:25.628196+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/./chat/consumers.py", line 5, in <module>
2023-09-29T13:50:25.628223+00:00 app[web.1]: from .models import Conversation, Message
2023-09-29T13:50:25.628223+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/./chat/models.py", line 5, in <module>
2023-09-29T13:50:25.628251+00:00 app[web.1]: from base.models import Company, Customer
2023-09-29T13:50:25.628251+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/./base/models.py", line 5, in <module>
2023-09-29T13:50:25.628278+00:00 app[web.1]: class Company(models.Model):
2023-09-29T13:50:25.628278+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/./base/models.py", line 20, in Company
2023-09-29T13:50:25.628333+00:00 app[web.1]: staff = models.ManyToManyField(get_user_model(), through='Role')
2023-09-29T13:50:25.628334+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 170, in get_user_model
2023-09-29T13:50:25.628356+00:00 app[web.1]: return django_apps.get_model(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, require_ready=False)
2023-09-29T13:50:25.628357+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 203, in get_model
2023-09-29T13:50:25.628398+00:00 app[web.1]: self.check_apps_ready()
2023-09-29T13:50:25.628398+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 138, in check_apps_ready
2023-09-29T13:50:25.628431+00:00 app[web.1]: raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
2023-09-29T13:50:25.628449+00:00 app[web.1]: django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
2023-09-29T13:50:25.808196+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2023-09-29T13:50:25.838513+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

`
```

**asgi.py**

```
import os

from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
import chat.routing

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'nanochat.settings')
django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": get_asgi_application(),
    "websocket": URLRouter(
        chat.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
    ),
})
```

**settings.py**

```
`INSTALLED_APPS = [
     'daphne',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'base',
    'accounts',
    'payment',
    'common',
    'utils',
    'notification',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
    # 'drf_spectacular',
    'channels',
    'drf_yasg',
    'corsheaders',
    'push_notifications',
    'chat',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]



ASGI_APPLICATION = "nanochat.asgi.application"
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': "channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer"
        }
    }
`
```

**Procfile**

```
release: python manage.py migrate
web: daphne nanochat.asgi:application --port $PORT --bind 0.0.0.0 -v2
```

I've checked the order of imports and ensured that I'm not importing any models or modules before calling get_asgi_application(). I've also verified my environment variables and database configuration.

What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it to successfully deploy my ASGI application on Heroku?

Thank you for your help.

I've checked the order of imports and ensured that I'm not importing any models or modules before calling get_asgi_application(). I've also verified my environment variables and database configuration.

What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it to successfully deploy my ASGI application on Heroku?

Thank you for your help.